# In fluids, what is the difference between the two forces in the formula $F=pA$ and $F=\rho Vg$?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, pressure, fluid-statics

I was doing a question on fluids which is:

> A living room has floor dimensions of $3.5 m$ and $4.2 m$ and a height of $2.4 m$. What does the air in the room weigh when the air pressure is $1.0 atm$?

So what I did was since $m=\rho V$ and weight $(F_g) = mg$, I let $Fg=pVg$ and solved it. However, when I tried to solve it using the formula $P=F/A$ and thus $F=PA$, I got a completely off answer. So my question is, why are these two values of forces different? Is the $F$ from $F=PA$ not $F_g$? Thanks beforehand :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not the same.

In $m = \rho g$, you're taking the density of the air times the volume to calculate the mass, then using that to find the weight.  So $F$ calculated from that is the weight of that particular amount of air.  The air pressure is only used to determine the density.

But the force on the floor is not (solely) from the weight of the air in the room.  Because the room is not sealed, it includes the weight of all the air above the room as well.  The weight of this column of air is what causes the pressure at ground level.  The second $F$ is the weight of the room air plus the air above.

Comment: *Because the room is not sealed* I wonder what your answer
would be if the room were sealed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of pressures.

One because of the mass of the body and the other because of the presence of enthalpy in the body.Now coming to your case assuming the room to be sealed,generally the atmospheric air will be at a temperature or $27°C$ say on an avg.Then this $300K(27+273.15)$  will lead to increase in pressure that you are talking about.Of course it also have some pressure because of weight but very very small almost negligible. Coming to other type of pressure that comes from weight of body.Let us consider a body of mass $10kg$ with area of contact of $1m^2$ on ground.The body will exert a pressure of $10 \times 9.81/1 Pa$ which is the formula that you have mentioned.

Comment: @bowlofred why didnt youconsider the effect of temperature on pressure

Comment: Because it is the major thing here.If it is a open room obviously the pressure is atm.pressure.ok then why is the pressure of air outside 10120 bar?This would surely answer the question